# A stop order won't be automatically fired in after-hours trading?

Tags: stocks, broker

I set up a `stop-loss order` with `GT90` duration at `10.5` when the stock is trading at around `11.6` during regular trading time. But in `after-hour` trading time it dropped suddenly to `9.5` due to some rather bad news. When I took a look at my order-status panel it's not sold.

Just wondering, is it reasonable?

I am using firstrade.com as my broker.

update:

1. this is how I put the order (2 hours after market open):

> [image]

2. this is how the order looks like now (market closed):

> [image]

Comment: Did you place a limit stop order or a market stop order?

Comment: What does duration GT90 stand for?

Comment: @MarkDoony Presumably it's a Good-Til-Canceled order that auto-cancels after 90 days.

Comment: Original poster and over the counter (in reply to agameplayer’s inquiry. Can’t “add a comment” without a full account and don’t need another login to remember.)

Answer (score 8):

Stop orders and stop limit orders typically do not execute during extended hours after the general market session has closed.

Stop orders are market orders and market orders especially are not executed during extended hours.

Although there are exceptions because a broker can say one thing and do another thing with the way order types are presented to customers vs what their programming actually does. The regulatory burden is a slap on the wrist, so you need to ask the broker what their practices are.

Orders created during normal market hours do not execute in extended sessions, different orders would have to be made during the extended session.

Your stop order should execute if the normal market hour price stays below your stop price. So a stop limit would actually be worse here, because a stop limit will create a limit order which may never get hit (since it is above the best bid best ask)

Comment: +1  Indeed.  If OP's original order was actually sent to an exchange, then by definition it can't be executed after hours, because that's when exchanges are closed.  And if the broker decided to keep the order in its own internal dark pool, then those are also closed after hours.  No resting order submitted to a lit exchange can ever execute after hours.  This is why after-hours trading is so sparse -- both sides have to purposefully want to use an OTC venue for the trade.

Comment: what does `OP` and `OTC` mean in this comment? Thanks